# Javascript: How to make a variable "private" only for the current layer of recursion?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, recursion

I am trying to make a function that will include a for-loop. However, in the loop, it calls itself and the "next layer" resets the counter. I know that this would work in PHP but I cannot figure out how to keep that counter "protected" from being reset by the inner for-loop.

My original code is more complicated, so I simplified the example to this:

```
function test(a=5){
  for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    console.log(i);
    test(a-1);
  }
}

test();
```

When I run this I get "1 1 1 1".

What I expect is "1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 1 4 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 1" (tried the same function in PHP).

Comment: You forgot to declare `i` as a local variable, so it's implicitly global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a variable with out `var,let,const` the variable will become a global variable. So in your code you are creating a global variable and then arr the recursive function have same `i` incremented.

You need to use `let` to declare `i`.

```js
function test(a=5){
  for(let i=0; i<a; i++){
    console.log(i);
    test(a-1);
  }
}

test();
```

Comment: One simple word that completely fixed my whole code (I am quite new in JS)... Thanks a lot :)